# Login if user is active using Laravel Breeze

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8

I've changed it in the LoginRequest.php file at authenticate function, but it doesn't work.

```
if (! Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password', ['active' => 1]), $this->filled('remember'))) {
 RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

 throw ValidationException::withMessages([
  'email' => __('auth.failed'),
 ]);
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be  `$this->only('email', 'password', 'active')`, why to pass the value?

Comment: I have tried this code but it still doesn't work. I want if active == 1 can login, but if active == 0 it will not login. So is there anything that needs to be added in another auth function?

Comment: pass the value along where you pass the email & password values not do it here, the function attempt, take 1d array called $credentials as first argument, if you pass `['active' => 1]`, it does not work.

Answer (score 9):

The `active` part needs to be added to the array passed to `attempt`, which needs to be merged with the array returned from `only`:

```
Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password') + ['active' => 1]) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if user is active and then login the user you can check that just inside auth::attempt

like this:

```
  if (Auth::attempt([...], $remember_me)) {

        if (Auth::user()->is_active == 1) {
            user-will-stay-login
        }
        else{
           User::logout();
           return \redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this :

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

    if (Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'),)) {
        if (Auth::user()->isActive != 1) {
            Auth::logout();
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => __('auth.suspend'),
            ]);
        }
    } else {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => __('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }
    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}
```